# Trying to put Arabic or Kurdish text inside TeXView

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to show math equation along side Arabic or Kurdish texts but the problem that happens it when there is Arabic or Kurdish text in between the equation last number or symbol will shift to the star and that will make everything wrong here is my code :

```
TeXView(
      style: TeXViewStyle(
         textAlign: TeXViewTextAlign.right,
         contentColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      child: TeXViewDocument(r"""کاتێک \(a \ne 0 \), چۆنی باشی \(ax^2 + bx + c = 0\) دەکاتە؟""",
    ),
)
```

and here is the result of it:
[image: result]

I'm using **flutter_tex** package, and the text i'm getting it from backend and its one string.

Answer (score 0):

Since the package does not provide to specify the *local* property like in **Text** widget, use this instead it'll solve your problem :

```
          Directionality(
            textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
            child: TeXView(
              style: TeXViewStyle(
                textAlign: TeXViewTextAlign.right,
                contentColor: Colors.white,
              ),
              child: TeXViewDocument(
                r"""کاتێک \(a \ne 0 \), چۆنی باشی \(ax^2 + bx + c = 0\) دەکاتە؟""",
                style: TeXViewStyle(contentColor: Colors.red),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: I have tired it, and sadly that was not the fix for it and still produced same issue

Comment: Try a different text and see how it reacts to it and work based on that, I think this is the solution for now until the package owners did something